# How to set salary for object before adding it arraylist

Tags: java

Im reading data from a text file 
which includes information about employees details
as the following:

> H ,name ,socialNumber,hours,rate
>   S,name,social number,salary

and add them to tow lists.

If they are hourly employee:

```
H.add(new Hourly(name ,number,hour,rate);
```

Else if they were salaried:

```
S.add(new salaried(name,number);
```

The question is: how to add the salary for the employee before adding the object to the list?
hourly = rate*hours
Salaried = salary
I have attribute salary
and mutator method which sets double salary

I also set the salary after adding the object to the list,
but the took the last salary form the text 
The first 1500 the second 2000

Comment: Can't you just calculate that in the constructor of the objects, or create the objects above the `add` line, and set the salary before adding it in? Show some code as a [mcve] and clarify what exactly you need help with.

Comment: It works , obj 1 , 2  then set salary   cause I know there is only tow employee What if I don’t now how many salaried employee? How many objects should  I create ?

Comment: I tried to upload a photo of the project but it couldn’t upload

Comment: All relevant code should be posted here directly as text.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the Salary before adding it to the List, you can define the new Entry before, change the Salary and then adding it:

```
Salaried s = Salaried(name,number);
s.setSalary(computedSalary);
S.add(s);
```

I hope that help you,

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You may consider the builder pattern, which offers a flexible way of constructing objects:

```
public class Salaried {
  String name;
  String socialNumber;
  Double salary; 

  ...

  public static class Builder {
    String name;
    String socialNumber;
    Double salary;

    public Builder(String name, String socialNumber) {
      this.name = name;
      this.socialNumber = socialNumber;
    }

    public Builder salary(Double salary) {
      this.salary = salary;
      return this;
    }

    public Salaried build() {
      Salaried salaried = new Salaried(name, socialNumber);
      salaried.setSalary(salary);
      return salaried;
    }
  }
}

S.add(new Salaried.Builder("bob","12345678").salary(40000).build());
```